# Chat Platform Website/App

Tags: api, platform, messenger

i've been dieing to find out how to do this.

I have got a group that helps people overcome fears depression and things like that(mental health). I been wondering to find a platform(open source) or something like that, that will let me create an app or an website where the website is just a chat website. Think of it as messenger but i want it to be all private.

For example the staff is on the left menu and the person can press and talk with him/her in private about their problems.

Do you have any recommendations? Like I've been dieing to know and it will benefit me a lot.! THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious answer here would be some sort of email client -  However, that may not be what you're looking for. Are you looking for an xmpp like client? You may want to try https://conversejs.org/... You will also have to get an xmpp server, however, you can just work with Google's integrated XMPP server. If you host with DreamHost, it's in the Goodies tab, under 'Jabber'

Comment: Not 100% sure what you've said but ill have a look. Thank you!